# How to pass props props from Parent to this.props.children in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have difficulties trying to pass props to `this.props.children`. I know there's a few similar posts, however, I believe I have tried most of the accepted solutions, and it's still not behaving and expected. So, I guess I'm missing something vital.

**The general idea is this**: I have a `<NavBar>` component that I would like to wrap around my pages as shown below. I'd like for the wrapped page to accept props passed down from the `<NavBar>` component.

```
<NavBar>
    <Container>
        <Grid container>
            <Grid item>
               ...
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Container>
</NavBar>
```

Currently my `<NavBar>` is defined as such:

```
class NavBar extends React.Component<React.PropsWithChildren<NavBarProps>, NavBarState>
```

So, my component has a prop `children?: React.ReactNode`. In my `render()` method I am rendering an `<AppBar>` (from Material UI library) underneath which I display the `children` similar as such:

```
render() {
    const {children} = this.props;
    return(
        <>
            <AppBar>...</AppBar>
            {children}
        </>
    )
}
```

**Some attempts I've had**:

```
render() {
    const children = React.cloneElement(this.props.children as React.ReactElement, {
        test: "test"
    });

    return(
        <>
            <AppBar>...</AppBar>
            {children}
        </>
    )
}
```

**What I expect**: In this case, I would like to be able to access the `test` props from any page wrapped within `<NavBar>` like `this.props.test`

**I also tried**:

```
const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children as React.ReactElement, (child) =>
    React.cloneElement(child, { test: "test" })
);
```

&

```
const children = React.Children.map<ReactNode, ReactNode>(this.props.children, (child) => {
  if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
    return React.cloneElement(child, { test: "test" });
  }
});
```

**Result so far**: I've been unsuccessful and trying to access `this.props.test` from my page returns `undefined`.

Comment: React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {...this.props}) should do. with React 16.6 you can use context API for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your third attempt. Here is a working example using that method. Notice unlike your second attempt, you do need to `return` from the `map`.

```js
function Test() {
  return (
    <Parent>
      <Child />
    </Parent>
  );
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {test: 'test'});
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Parent</h3>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Child</h3>
        Test Prop: {this.props.test}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```